# Post request inside php code var anidade

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I am working with Dygraphs to chart Arduino sensor data.I need to get a subtract between two data so i am using php inside a script function but it doesn't work.It is possible to include

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var csv = [
      '<?php
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/***/feed.csv?key=***&start=<?php echo $_POST['day_ini'];?>%20<?php echo $_POST['hour_ini'];?>&end=<?php echo $_POST['day_end'];?>%20<?php echo $_POST['hour_end'];?>", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  ...
    ?>','2015-11-02 20:54:50 UTC,1049703,5,5'
    ];
```

This is all my function code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csv = [
  '<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/***/feed.csv?key=***&start=2015-11-02%2020:50:45&end=2015-11-02%2021:50:45", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 50, ",")) !== FALSE) {
if($row == 1){ $row++; continue; }
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    if(strpos($data[$c], 'Finished') !== false) {
    $c++;
echo  $data[$c] . "," ; }
    Else{
        echo $data[$c] . "," ;
        }
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>','2015-11-02 20:54:50 UTC,1049703,5,5'

  //... etcetera
];



        function getPairDifference(pair) {
            //"pair" is a zero-based integer.
            // "0" will return a difference between csv rows "0" & "1"
            // "1" will return a difference between csv rows "1" & "2"
            // etcetera...

            var firstVal = parseInt(csv[pair].split(",")[3]);
            var secondVal = parseInt(csv[pair + 1].split(",")[3]);
            return firstVal - secondVal;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i += 1) {
            // Demo code to visualize numbers.
            // Actual function call of interest is simply "getPairDifference( i )"
            var plot = getPairDifference(i);
              //  $("<div></div>").text(plot).appendTo("body");
$(function() {
  $("#chart3").chart({
  template: "line_basic_6",
  tooltips: {
    serie1: [plot],
    width:20,
    height:15,
  },
  values: {
    serie1: [plot]
  },
  labels: ["Period 1","Period 2"],
  defaultSeries: {
    type: "bar",
    stacked: true
  },
  series: {
    serie3: {
      type: "line",
      stacked: false,
      axis: "r"
    }
  },
  axis: {
    r: {
      max: 100,
      suffix: "%"
    }
  }
});

});

$.elycharts.templates['line_basic_6'] = {
  type: "line",
  margins: [10, 40, 40, 30],
  defaultSeries: {
    highlight: {
      newProps: {
        r: 8,
        opacity: 1
      },
      overlayProps: {
        fill: "white",
        opacity: 0.2
      }
    }
  },
  series: {
    serie1: {
      color: "90-#003000-#009000",
      tooltip: {
        frameProps: {
          stroke: "green"
        }
      }
    },


  },
  defaultAxis: {
    labels: true
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      labelsRotate: 0,
      labelsProps: {
        font: "11px Verdana"
      }
    }
  },
  features: {
    grid: {
      draw: true,
      forceBorder: true,
      ny: 5
    }
  },
  barMargins: 180

};            
        }       
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

no need to echo like that and you are using `<?php` inside another `<?php` before closing that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var csv = [
            '<?php
                $row = 1;
                if (($handle = fopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/***/feed.csv?key=***&start={$_POST['day_ini']}%20{$_POST['hour_ini']}&end={$_POST['day_end']}%20{$_POST['hour_end']}", "r")) !== FALSE) {

                }
                ?>', '2015-11-02 20:54:50 UTC,1049703,5,5'
        ];

    </script>
```

And i am not sure of `}`, please check that once.

Comment: Hello.Thaks for your reply. The `}` you are refering to is in post?,bacause in my post it is [. I am using:`https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/***/feed.csv?key=***&start=2015-11-02%2020:50:45&end=2015-11-02%2020:50:45` and it work .

Comment: there was no closing `}` in your code... i just added there.

Comment: ok,i have edited my question to show the code of the Dygraph chart fuction to this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have missunderstood something about PHP and Javascript.

Javascript gets sended to the Client, so it works in the Browser and also get's executed.

PHP altough gets executed on the Server first, there lies your problem, you can't execute on the Client something that needs to be done by a Server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to be careful with that but i think that perhaps my function is too much anidade?